# Unable to run/deploy iOS app in iPhone simulator

Tags: uno-platform

I am not able to deploy the Uno platform ios app to the iPhone simulator. My visual studio has connected to a remote mac. when I try to run ios app, I get the error in the simulator. you can see in the below image.

I can able to run all other types of projects of my Uno platform project except ios and macOS. please let me know what I am missing?

My git repo: https://github.com/avikeid2007/Repayabl

[image]

Comment: This looks like a build failure. Does a rebuilt work properly when connected to the mac ?

Comment: I have seen this happen several times with various reasons: Mac remote connection got broken (disconnect and reconnect), Mac requires restarting, Visual Studio requires restarting - one of these should fix it